# Update object data-members in React state doesn't trigger re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using TypeScript and React to try to implement my custom types in React component. However the component is not re-rendering if data members of object in state has updated.

Here's my code:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  surname: string;

  constructor(name: string, surname: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [new Person("Alpha", "A"), new Person("Bravo", "B")]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.state.persons[0].name = "Zulu";
            this.state.persons[0].surname = "Z";
          }}
        >
          Change A to Z
        </button>

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
              persons: [...this.state.persons, new Person("Charlie", "C")]
            });
          }}
        >
          Add C
        </button>

        <button onClick={() => { this.forceUpdate(); }}> Force Update </button>

        {this.state.persons.map(person => (
          <p>
            {person.name} {person.surname}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Full Code Snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ab9a7c)

If I click on `Change A to Z` nothing will change - unless `Add C` or `Force Update` is clicked. I am assuming React cannot detect changes made in `Person` therefore no re-render.

I have some questions about this problem.

- Is this approach (custom datatype as state) recommended to use in React

  - If yes - how do I make this work? (React able to detect changes made in `Person`)
  - If no - what is the recommended approach to use custom datatype in React?

Comment: Your `Change A to Z` button is **directly manipulating state**. Never do this. React won't know when you change state that way, and that's only *one* of the reasons why you shouldn't. Always use `setState` to update state values

Comment: @Jayce444 - Thanks, does you mean I should do it like this?  `let localPersons = [...this.state.persons];
localPersons[0].name = "Zulu";
localPersons[0].surname = "Z";
this.setState({persons: localPersons});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will not re-render by default if every element in the new state is `===` to every element in the old state. You also have to call `setState` in order to trigger a re-render. Your `Change A to Z` is failing on both counts - you need to both create a new `persons` array without mutating what's currently in state, and then call `setState` with the new array.

Also, having a `Person` instance doesn't look to be accomplishing anything, since there are no methods on the class - and it'll make changing the state harder, so I'd remove `Person` entirely. Try

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [{ name: 'Alpha', surname: 'A' }, { name: 'Bravo', surname: 'B' }]
    };
  }
```

Then change

```
      onClick={() => {
        this.state.persons[0].name = "Zulu";
        this.state.persons[0].surname = "Z";
      }}
```

to

```
onClick={() => {
  this.setState({
    persons: [{ name: 'Zulu', surname: 'Z' }, ...this.state.persons.slice(1)]
  });
}}
```

The

```
persons: [{ name: 'Zulu', surname: 'Z' }, ...this.state.persons.slice(1)]
```

effectively immutably replaces the first element of the array with the new `Zulu` object.

Comment: Thanks, I have a question my `Person` is just a sample class - the class I'll be implementing is more complex (reference to other object, nested data, etc.). Will this solution works for me?

Comment: Nested data is fine. I would highly recommend trying to only put *pure data* into state when possible. While you could put instances into state, it would make changing the state significantly more difficult. Methods on the class, if they exist, could easily lead one to try to perform impure actions that should not be done in React. But if you think you can avoid the pitfalls, go ahead.

Comment: If you use instances, you'll just need to replace the `{ name: 'Zulu', surname: 'Z' }` occurrences with `new Person('Zulu', 'surname')`. Even if you just want to update an object without replacing it entirely, you'll still need `new Person` to avoid mutation. (state mutation is forbidden in React)